# flutter : How migrate to Null safety

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a project that is developed with Flutter v2.2.3 and Dart version 2.13.4 working great,I should migrate to Null safety , I upgraded sdk to 2.12.0 in pubspec.yaml but I got the error ends with:

```
The migration tool didn't start, due to analysis errors.

The following steps might fix your problem:
1. Set the lower SDK constraint (in pubspec.yaml) to a version before 2.12.
2. Run `dart pub get`.
3. Try running `dart migrate` again.
```

How I can get the url migration suggestions to complete migration task ?
How i can fix it ?
thank you in advance

Comment: You need to run `dart migrate` *before* editing your `pubspec.yaml` file.  Once you set the Dart SDK minimum version to 2.12.0, you're assumed to have already migrated your code to null-safety.  Change the minimum version to, say, 2.10.0.  If you still get an error, then run `flutter analyze` and fix any reported errors.

Comment: how i ca  get url migration suggestions ? @jamesdlin

Comment: I have 607 errors

Comment: The non-serious errors you can disable by [disabling lints in your `analysis_options.yaml` file](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options).  You should fix serious errors.  In many cases, a single fix to the code can fix many errors, so you don't necessarily have 607 changes to make.